# How to implement variable dependency versions in Maven3 using _profiles_?

Tags: variables, dependencies, version, interpolation, maven-3

We need to build project with different versions of deps (in this example, Postgres 8 and Postgres 9). Also, our developers have different versions of DBs on their computers.

I'm tried to do something like this:

```
    <profile>
        <id>postgres9</id>
        <properties>
            <postgres.driver.version>
                9.0-801
            </postgres.driver.version>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>postgres8</id>
        <properties>
            <postgres.driver.version>
                8.3-603
            </postgres.driver.version>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgres.driver.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <properties>
        <postgres.driver.version>8.3-603</postgres.driver.version>
    </properties>



    mvn clean test -Ppostgres9
```

But it didn't work. Profile variable is not overriding pom variable at all. Also, I cannot achieve that even with the ~/.m2/settings.xml.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: This appears correct.  Perhaps this dependency is overridden/repeated elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

We've been trying to do similar things in our projects for quite a while.  The only way that consistently works is to pass -Dpostgres.driver.version=8.3-603.  For some reason, variables are not interpolated before dependencies are computed.

Oddly enough, it seems to work on *some* of my projects under Maven 3.0.2.  I'm trying to investigate deeper now.

Comment: I recently discovered a maven-dependencies-plugin, maybe it can be done with it, but I have not checked it out for now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
Moving the version (with the property) from dependency to dependencyManagement in the parent pom solved it for me:

**old:**
pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgres.driver.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**new:**
pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

parent pom:

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgres.driver.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```